# Can a realistic rubber mannequin be turned inside-out.

Tags: general-topology

A realistic human-shaped mannequin is made of topological-grade rubber.

All the body cavities that are accessible from outside without piercing any tissue, are faithfully reproduced, for example the digestive tract and the nostrils. Ear drums are assumed to be intact.

The interior of the dummy is coloured pink and the outside is sprayed blue.

Is it possible for the dummy to be turned inside-out to form a sphere with a few holes in such a way that only pink shows and only blue is hidden?

Comment: New advertisement phrase: "topological-grade materials".  To be understood only by mathematicians.

Comment: What's not clear to me is whether "turned inside out" means "is there an embedding of this surface with this property?" or "is there a regular homotopy of this initial embedding to the inside-out embedding? " or "is there an isotopy of ...?"

Comment: It's not even clear to me what "exterior" means here. Do the pink and blue regions share a boundary? If so, what shape is it? A disjoint union of circles maybe?

Comment: Does the "interior" include "All the body cavities that are accessible from outside without piercing any tissue," and is the "outside" every other part of the surface?

Comment: @MJD - 'Exterior' means what most people would think of. You can imagine someone being spray-tanned. There would be an arbitrary but clear boundary just inside each nostril. Similarly at the lips and the anus. Also the urethra - even though a cul-de-sac - would be pink inside. Someone has mentioned the Eustachian tubes as well.

Comment: I guess that you are forcing the regions of pink and blue to not be connected. Of course you can't under those conditions. Why ask?

Comment: Viewing the mannequin and it's GI tract as an arm warmer, it's possible to turn both inside out. The blue will then be on the inside, the pink on the outside.

Comment: @Charlie Frohman - Because I'm not a mathematician and I'm curious. The key is visibility. Thus if you turned the bladder/urethra (a dead-end) inside out I can see that a simple hole wouldn't do the job. You'd have to have a central pink region that abutted a surrounding pink region all round it's circumference. I'm trying to get my head around how adding colour affects the normally monochrome aspects of topology.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, humans are homologous to a torus because of the digestive track. A torus cannot be bent into a sphere.

Comment: There is a nose.

Comment: Good point, ears are also connected to the nose.

Comment: This is not a true sphere because surface holes are allowed - just not big enough to see through.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty clear that the blue region is connected and the pink region is not.  On the other hand I can imagine painting a blue band around a pink sphere and then deforming the sphere in such a way that the blue band is folded upon itself and "hidden" while the pink regions remain visible, but what you have then is not a "sphere with a few holes," you have something that looks (from the outside) like a sphere separated into two parts by a crack.